# MVC 5 Real-time SMS with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sms, signalr

I am new to web development but I have a project done in VB6, it is a real time send and receive sms application. It uses a GSM modem connected to the server. My company asked me to make a web based version of my application, using ASP.NET MVC.

So I studied MVC about a month ago, created basic CRUD apps, read about SignalR but I don't want to start up a project that I am not confident if its feasible or not. So my question is, is this project possible with the said technology? (MVC, SignalR, and a GSM Modem)

If it is, can you point me somewhere I could start reading for maybe you know a similar project that can guide me through.
And if it is not, can you suggest me the appropriate tech to use for this project to be feasible? (I prefer ASP.NET MVC)

A little detail about the functionality of the project: 
Has User Authentication - this user will have a simple "SMS box" type of thing which will update like a chatbox if an SMS is received in the GSM modem and this user can reply and use the GSM to send the SMS back to the sender.

IF anyone could help me, guide me, point me to some reading materials to make this project it would be greatly appreciated. Please post if you need clarifications and further explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Off the top of my head I think this would be possible using the frameworkds and tech you have outlined. There is a tutorial project with SignalR on the asp.net site. I'd do that to get your head around how it works (if you haben't already) and then from there you could tweak it to work with your gsm modem. I'm guessing you'd need some kind of service to bridge between the modem and the website.

Answer (score 0):

User,

There are many ways to achieve this, so I will explain a method that worked for me a while back doing exactly this.

Based on the information provided, I will assume that you have a windows desktop app, that can already talk to the modem and perform various functions.

Trying to perform that same tasks in a web application can be a hard path to go down, what I opted for was rather simple in my opinion. You really have two separate problems, one is getting the received messages to the web application and the other getting the web application to send messages to the modem.

For handling received messages, I created a simple web api in the web application and defined a post method that is able to receive a sms object. You will need to provide the url for this call to your code that resides in your modem project, which I would convert to a windows service, if it is not already. Then when your code fires when the modem has received a sms, you simply create a object, serialize it to xml or json and then call the post method in your web api. This will give you the chance to use SignalR to notify clients or whatever else you might need to do. This is honestly is the simple part and you have the "real-time" handling ability now for receive.

For sending, there again where many options, I opted for database polling from the code inside the windows service, so when a user wants to reply or send a message, the message gets stored in a table in a database, from where the service code will pick it up and send it, once sent it will mark a field in the table as sent and possibly add a date and time as to when this happened. Again your service code could call another method on your web api, that will notify your app, that a message was sent and again you could notify the end user.

As for database polling, there are various methods, you could simply run some code every minute or some configurable value to see if there are any unsent messages.

You could use SqlDependency and handle the events in real time, you would register an event against the table where messages to be sent will be inserted into and when this happens, your service code will receive a real time event which can be handled.

You could also in the windows service, create a service, even a self hosted web api again, which can be called from your web application when it wants to send an email.

I did various implementations based on client requirements, but for me hosting either a wcf service or web api in the windows service project, proved to be the best in my opinion. You then simply have a configuration section in your web application, and provide the service address, or uri for the post method.

I hope that I have given you enough ideas to get a starting point for your project.